# change the appearance of input type number

Tags: html, css

I tried this code but nothing happened. I need to change the arrows by an image  also rotate but I could not.

```
<style>
input[type=number] {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0 8px;
}
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    width:8px;
    color: #333;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}    
input[type=number]:hover::-webkit-inner-spin-button { 
    background: #eee url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYySO.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;  
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    padding: 4px;
    position: relative;
    right: 4px;
    border-radius: 28px;
}
</style>

<input type="number" value="0">
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYySO.png

http://jsfiddle.net/josefelipe87/wf0w0dhw/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/wf0w0dhw/1/ working fine in Chrome

Comment: `transform: rotate(90deg)`

Comment: What browser are you testing in? This works fine for me in Chrome. It does *not* work in Firefox or IE, but you can't expect it to because you're using `-webkit-` prefixes, which means that it's an experimental feature which is only supported by a specific browser. What you're trying to do cannot be done in a cross-browser compatible way.

Comment: it true, in Chrome works fine

Comment: Well, if you're expecting it to work in any other browsers, the bad news for you is that it doesn't. It's a Chrome-specific feature. If you want it cross-browser, you'll need to write the buttons for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Different code for different browser in CSS

For mozila

```
    input[type=number] { 
      -moz-appearance: textfield;
      appearance: textfield;
      margin: 0; 
    }
```

For Chrome

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
      -webkit-appearance: none; 
      margin: 0; 
}
```